# How to use variable in key for a properties in yml with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I use a variable as key for a Map in a yaml property file.

Example properties.yml :

```
aVariableAsKey: key
anOtherVariableAsValue: value
app:
  my-map:
    ${aVariableAsKey} : ${anOtherVariableAsValue}
```

MyProperties class :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class MyProperties {
     private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
     //getter and setter
}
```

Using this example result with the MyProperties class having { "aVariableAsKey": "value" } in "myMap".

Thanks

Comment: what is your question ? and what's wrong with your code ?

Answer (score 0):

define new config class for example

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("my-map")
public class MyappConfig {
     aVariableAsKey;
     anOtherVariableAsValue; //you can assign aVariableAsKey to this variable
     //getter and setter

}
```

///Add this code to assign aVariableAsKey inside of Yaml code

```
 my-map:
    aVariableAsKey : key
```

Comment: I'm using a Map cause I don't know the keys before. I can't create a class which list them.

Comment: You can assign any value to aVariableAsKey and anOtherVariableAsValue via .yml file. And by using your MyProperties class, you can map keys to each other.

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand what you mean. You are suggesting to deconstruct the map into a list of object containing the pair key/value ?